# Convert json string with duplicate keys into javascript array

Tags: javascript, json

I feel like this should be simple but I can't get my head around it. I'm trying to use Google Charts to display some simple data, I've got this data in a json string in a format like.

```
var json1 = [{"email":"abc@xyz","noOfOrders":"223"},{"email":"bcd@xyz.com","noOfOrders":"12"},{"email":"cde@xyz.com","noOfOrders":"132"}]
```

and I'm trying to get that into Google charts which has to be formatted as such.

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Customer', 'Number of Orders'],
    ['abc@xyz.com', 223],
    ['bcd@xyz.com', 12],
    ['cde@xyz.com', 123]
  ]);
```

I'm trying to achieve with this javascript.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do I get the shown json string into the shown array format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through the JSON data and build the array needed for the chart.

```
var json = JSON.parse( [{...}] );  //parse the json string first, converting it to an array
var opts = [['Customer', 'Number of Orders']]; //add the headers now

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    opts[] = [ json[i].email, json[i].noOfOrders ];
}

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( data );
```